# Casting c_str() only works for short strings

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c++11, casting

I'm using a C library in C++ and wrote a wrapper. At one point I need to convert an `std::string` to a c-style string. There is a class with a function, which returns a string. Casting the returned string works if the string is short, otherwise not. Here is a simple and reduced example illustrating the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class StringBox {
public:
  std::string getString() const { return text_; }

  StringBox(std::string text) : text_(text){};

private:
  std::string text_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const unsigned char *castString = NULL;
  std::string someString = "I am a loooooooooooooooooong string";  // Won't work
  // std::string someString = "hello";  // This one works

  StringBox box(someString);

  castString = (const unsigned char *)box.getString().c_str();
  std::cout << "castString: " << castString << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Executing the file above prints this to the console:

> castString:

whereas if I swap the commenting on `someString`, it correctly prints

> castString: hello

How is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are invoking `c_str` on a temporary string object retuned by the `getString()` member function. The pointer returned by `c_str()` is only valid as long as the original string object exists, so at the end of the line where you assign `castString` it ends up being a dangling pointer. Officially, this leads to undefined behavior.

So why does this work for short strings? I suspect that you're seeing the effects of the Short String Optimization, an optimization where for strings less than a certain length the character data is stored inside the bytes of the string object itself rather than in the heap. It's possible that the temporary string that was returned was stored on the stack, so when it was cleaned up no deallocations occurred and the pointer to the expired string object still holds your old string bytes. This seems consistent with what you're seeing, but it still doesn't mean what you're doing is a good idea. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! The funny thing is the code worked perfectly fine for months on my other system. Only now that I updated Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10 and reinstalled everything it changed. I guess that's the undefined behaviour...

Comment: And thanks for the elaboration. Can you explain what you mean by "not a good idea"? Or are you referring to my mistake of calling c_str() on an object returned by a function?

Comment: I guess the easy fix is: `std::cout << "castString: " << (const unsigned char *)box.getString().c_str() << std::endl;`

Comment: @potAito *The funny thing is the code worked perfectly fine for months on my other system* -- Welcome to the world of C++ programming, where programs that can work for **years** can have bugs in them, only to be discovered by making simple changes in the code, or running on another system.

Comment: @chqrlie nah, that will fix the output in the terminal but the problem will persist, meaning that `castString` will still have a faulty value.

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered! I accepted this answer as it is the most complete, but you all had the correct answers :)

Comment: @potAito: indeed, one cannot store the return value of `c_str()` on a temporary object for use in a later statement.

Answer (score 6):

`box.getString()` is an *anonymous temporary*. `c_str()` is only valid for the length of the variable.

So in your case, `c_str()` is *invalidated* by the time you get to the `std::cout`. The behaviour of reading the pointer contents is *undefined*.

(Interestingly the behaviour of your short string is *possibly* different due to `std::string` storing short strings in a different way.)

Comment: I would s/length/life

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand now!

Answer (score 6):

As you return by value

`box.getString()` is a temporary and so

`box.getString().c_str()` is valid only during the expression, then it is a dangling pointer.

You may fix that with

```
const std::string& getString() const { return text_; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to be clear: this fixes the problem because since the return value of `getString()` is now a reference to `_text` held by `StringBox` (and not an anonymous temporary as in your code), the result of `.c_str()` is valid for the lifespan of `_text`, or any other modifying operation on `_text`.

Answer (score 5):

`box.getString()` produces a temporary. Calling `c_str()` on that gives you a pointer to a temporary. After the temporary ceases to exist, which is immediately, the pointer is invalid, a **dangling pointer**.

Using a dangling pointer is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your code has UB independent of the length of the string: At the end of

```
castString = (const unsigned char *)box.getString().c_str();
```

the string returned by `getString` is destroyed and `castString` is a dangling pointer to the internal buffer of the destroyed string object.

The reason your code "works" for small strings is probably Small String Optimization: Short strings are (commonly) saved in the string object itself instead of being saved in an dynamically allocated array, and apparently that memory is still accesible and unmodified in your case.